# How to set custom object property on ASP.NET WebControl through markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, web-controls

I am struggling how to set a custom property which is suppose to point to an instance of my custom class on an ASP.NET webcontrol.

Sample web control:

```
public class CustomControl : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel
{
  public IFactory Factory { get; set; }
}
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{        
  public IFactory GetFactory { 
    get { return new CustomFactory(); } 
  }
}

public class CustomFactory : IFactory {}
```

The custom factory get initialized on the code behind. In my markup (not in code behind), I need to set the Factory property on my CustomControl to the instance in my code behind. 
Any variation of inline code that I tried did not work:

```
<asp:CustomControl ID="MyCustomControl" Factory="<%GetFactory%>" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomControl ID="MyCustomControl" Factory="<%=GetFactory%>" runat="server" />
```

Can anyone assist how to do this?

Comment: Why does it have to be in the markup?

Comment: To keep the code behind cleaner.

Comment: I'm not sure that's good reasoning - by attempting to keep the code behind cleaner, you're mucking up the markup. I don't necessarily see how adding one line of code makes the code behind messy.

Comment: My line of thinking was that the user drops the control into the aspx and sets all its properties there and does not have to go to the code behind to do anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't assign it on the control tag markup, the tag markup is rendered as html and has no logic to do it that way, html won't interpret te result of `GetFactory`.
What you can do is to set if on your markup, not it the control tag property, but inside code brackets just like this:

```
<%MyCustomControl.Factory = this.GetFactory;%>
```

Comment: I tried this, but on the OnInit of the custom control the Factory property is null. Does that code above execute on OnPreRender?

Comment: Doesn't matter if `Factory` property is null, because you're setting its value to `this.GetFactory`. What might be `null` is the control. In order to better understand this, check out what happens on [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx) (see **Render** section)

Comment: What I was trying to say is that I can do what you suggested, but that assignment will happen after the OnPreRender event and that is way too late for me.